# Satzglieder in »Ich gratuliere ihm zu seinem Erfolg.«

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Ich möchte die Satzstruktur des folgenden Satzes verstehen:

> Ich gratuliere ihm zu seinem Erfolg.

Ich habe bereits:

- *ich:* Subjekt
- *gratuliere* (oder *gratuliere zu*?): Prädikat
- *ihm:* Dativ-Objekt

Aber um welches Satzglied handelt es sich bei *zu seinem Erfolg* bzw. *seinem Erfolg?*

Answer (score 4):

Bei „zu seinem Erfolg“ handelt es sich um ein **[Präpositionalobjekt](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objekt_%28Grammatik%29#Pr.C3.A4positionalobjekt).**

> Er freut sich *über den Besuch.*
>   Sie überredete ihn *zur Teilnahme an der Tagung.*
>   Wir hoffen *auf bessere Zeiten.*
>   Sie dachte *an sein Versprechen.*
>   Er pochte *auf sein Recht.*
>   Sie klagen *auf Schadenersatz.*
>   Sie steht *zu ihrem Wort.*
>   Sie begnügen sich *mit einem matten Protest.*

Gewöhnlich liegt ein Präpositionalobjekt vor, wenn vom Prädikat eine bestimmte Präposition gefordert ist:

> Die Mannschaften warten *auf den Anpfiff.*
>   *(worauf?)*

Dagegen sind die Präpositionen in den adverbialen Bestimmungen oft austauschbar:

> Die Mannschaften warten *in der Kabine.*
>   Die Mannschaften warten *neben der Kabine.*
>   Die Mannschaften warten *an der Kabine.*
>   *(wo?)*

[Beispiele aus Duden – *Die Grammatik*]

Comment: Kannst Du bitte kurz erklären, was Du unter einem Präpositionalobjekt verstehst?
Kann ein Präpositionalobjekt einen casus haben und wenn ja, welcher ist es in diesem Fall?

Comment: @fragmich Ein Präpositionalobjekt kann im Akkusativ (Er pochte *auf sein Recht.*) oder im Dativ (Sie steht *zu ihrem Wort.*) stehen, je nach dem Kasus, der durch die Präposition gefordert wird.

Comment: Was ist allgemein formuliert ein Präpositionalobjekt und in welchem casus ist es dann im o.g. Satz?
Wie lautet das Prädikat? gratuliere oder gratuliere zu?

Comment: @fragmich: Das Verb müsste vollständig als "zu etwas gratulieren" angegeben werden. Das Verb "gratulieren" bestimmt also, dass die Präposition "zu" benutzt wird. Die Präposition "zu" wiederum bestimmt, dass das zugehörige Substantiv im Dativ stehen muss.

Comment: Siehe auch [hier](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzglied/Objekt/Praepositional.html) dazu, was allgemein formuliert ein Präpositionalobjekten ist. Das [Prädikat](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzglied/Praedikat/index.html?MenuId=Sentence23) selbst ist hier nur "gratuliere", aber das Prädikt bestimmt die anderen Satzglieder, hier nach dem Muster "jemandem (Dat.) zu etwas (Präp.Obj. Dat.) gratulieren".

Answer (score 2):

Es handelt sich dabei um eine [adverbiale Bestimmung.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung) Das Prädikat ist nur *gratuliere.* Der Satz wäre in der gekürzten Form »Ich gratuliere ihm« ja immer noch vollständig.

Comment: Kannst Du etwas erläutern, wie Du zu dieser Einschätzung gekommen bist? Wieso ist »immer noch vollständig« relevant (ist laut verlinkter Wikipedia-Seite kein gutes Kriterium)?

Comment: »Immer noch vollständig« ist für mich ein Indiz dafür, dass »zu« nicht zum Prädikat gehört. (Einmal ganz abgesehen davon, dass der Infinitiv nicht »zugratulieren« ist.)

Comment: Erstmal würde ich es begrüssen, wenn du die wichtigen Kernpunkte, was eine adverbiale Bestimmung ist, in der Antwort erklären würdest. Zum einen muss man dann nicht einen ganzen Wikipedia-Artikel lesen und zum anderen ist nicht sichergestellt, dass der Link für ewig lebt. Desweiteren erzählt mir Wikipedia etwas über adverbiale Bestimmungen "des Ortes, der Zeit, der Art und Weise, ..." Um was handelt es sich denn hier konkret? Und anscheinend wird hier auch vom Objekt abgegrenzt. Wieso ist es dann kein Präpositionalobjekt, wie in einer anderen Antwort vorgeschlagen?

Answer (score 2):

"Ich" = Subjekt
"gratuliere" = Prädikat 
"ihm" = Dativobjekt

> "zu seinem Erfolg" hat *adverbiale Funktion*

...für das Verb "gratuliere", genauer gesagt, es ist ein *Satzadverbiale*, dessen Information Einfluss auf die gesamte Satzaussage hat, nicht nur auf das Verb allein (was etwa bei "Ich gratuliere ihm kurz" der Fall wäre).

Von der Systematik her ist es ein *Präpositivkomplement*, da es die Aussage des *Prädikats* mittels einer *Präposition* ergänzt.

Quellen: [Satzadverbiale](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/termwb.ansicht?v_id=242), [Präpositivkomplement](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=1540#abs8)

Comment: Gibt es nicht einen Unterschied zwischen adverbialen Bestimmungen und Präpositionalobjekten?

Comment: Er besteht wohl darin, dass Präpositionalobjekte den Satz zwingend ergänzen, wenn es sonst kein Objekt gibt, anders als das Adverbiale. "Ich gratuliere ihm" allein funktioniert, "ich gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg" aber nicht. Hingegen funktioniert "Sie überredete ihn" allein, aber nicht "sie steht", "sie begnügen sich", "sie klagen", "er pochte", "wir hoffen", "sie dachte", "sie begnügen sich". Deswegen handelt es sich bei deinem Beispiel nicht um ein Präpositionalobjekt.

Comment: Moment... seit wann/wieso funktioniert "Ich gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg" nicht? https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=%22gratuliere+zu%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @Emanuel Was beweist eine Google-Suche? Gibt es etwas weniger Spezifisches? Im übrigen enthalten nur zwei (!) Google-Treffer auf der ersten Seite den konkreten Wortlaut "Ich gratuliere zu seinem..." bzw. "..zu dem...". Da bitte ich schon um etwas mehr Genauigkeit. Konkret: Bei "Ich gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg" ist die Sprechsituation nicht klar. Wem wird hier gratuliert? "Ihm" könnte man hier nicht weglassen. Sprache beruht zwar auf einer Konvention (könnte also irgendwie zusammengebaut sein, wenn alle einverstanden sind), diese beruft sich aber in der Realität gerne auf eine bestimmte Logik.

Comment: Nee. Wenn du so eine steile These in den Raum stellst, die sich millionenfach mit Praxisbeispielen widerlegen lässt, dann ist es an dir, da vernünftige Belege zu bringen. Was bringt dich zu der Aussage, dass es nicht geht? Wie kommst du darauf? Wo steht das? Hat die Mehrheit immer Recht? Gegenfrage: hast du immer Recht? Und von wegen Genauigkeit... deine These ist im Grunde "zu etwas gratulieren" ohne Dativobjekt geht nicht. Da reicht eine Suche "gratuliere zu" um das zu widerlegen. Das "seinen" habe ich hinzugefügt, um extra genau zu sein, was aber absolut nicht notwendig ist.

Comment: @Emanuel Es ist schwer zu argumentieren, wenn auf diese Argumente nicht eingegangen wird. Nochmals: Wie ist die Sprechsituation bei "Gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg?" Eine Ansprache z.B. an ein Team, bei der jemand für einen Erfolg besonders hervorgehoben wird? Die Gratulation an einen Lehrer, dessen Schüler erfolgreich war? "Gratuliere zu deinem Erfolg" ruft hingegen eine eindeutige Vorstellung hervor. Zu deiner Aussage, in Fragen der Sprache hätte die Mehrheit immer recht: der Mehrheit ist, falls du das noch nicht bemerkt hast, die Sprache reichlich egal. Vielen Dank, schöne Aussichten.

Comment: Das ist vielleicht ein Argument, wenn es darum geht, stilistisch einwandfreies Deutsch zu schreiben. Du bist ja Lektor. Da überrascht mich derartige Strenge nicht. Aber zu sagen "funktioniert nicht" ist die falsche Formulierung. Das solltest gerade du als Lektor wissen, denn es "funktioniert" tausendfach ganz wunderbar. Wenn du darauf schon eingehen willst, dann sag "ist schlechter Stil" oder "ist unpräzise, da die Sprachsituation nicht klar ist". Aber nicht "funktioniert nicht". Das ist faktisch schlicht falsch. "Sie steht" funktioniert übrigens auch. Genauso wie "wir hoffen".

Comment: Den DV habe ich gemacht, weil ich vergessen hatte, dass die Aussage, die ich für falsch halte, im Kommentar war. Habe ihn entfernt. Und was die Merhheit angeht... wenn alle immer nur das machen würden, was die gelernten Schreiber sagen, dann würden wir heute genauso sprechen, wie vor 500 Jahren. Hätte auch was, aber mir persönlich ist Sprache, die im Fluss ist, lieberer.

Comment: @Emanuel Wenn ich von "funktionieren" spreche, gehe ich von einer Kommunikationssituation aus, in der die Partner über einander und die Mitteilung selbst möglichst wenig Vorwissen haben. Natürlich trifft das speziell auf Gesprächssituationen sehr oft nicht zu, auf geschriebene Texte umso håufiger. Ich finde, wir sollten speziell den Nicht-Deutschsprachigen hier die Chance geben, die Feinheiten und Differenzierungen und die Logik des Deutschen zu sehen und anzuwenden.

Comment: Ja, aber genau das tust du mit so einem Kommentar nicht. Du sagst "Ich gratuliere ..." funktioniert nicht, ohne Begrünung. Danach gibst du weitere Beispiele, von denen die Hälfte falsch ist/kein Beispiel ist. Damit hilfst du nicht, sondern du verwirrst. Wenn du helfen willst, dann mach eine klare Aussage wie "Für mein Sprachempfinden ist 'Ich gratuliere zu seinem..." unvollständig, da blah blah bla". Damit kann der Lerner was anfangen und kann gleichzeitig die vielen Tausend Gegenbeispiel (auch in Print) einordnen. Mit "funktioniert nicht" nicht.

Comment: @Emanuel Die Relativierung, die du von mir forderst, hältst du leider selbst nicht ein, wenn du meine Beispiele apodiktisch als falsch bezeichnest. Du hast auch eine eigene Art, mit den Argumenten des Diskussionspartners umzuspringen. Deine Google-basierte quantitative Belegmethode halte ich zumindest für fragwürdig, weil du sie äußerst beliebig und ohne Definition anwendest. Ich finde es unnötig schwierig, unter diesen Umständen zu diskutieren, deshalb belassen wir es einfach dabei.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, was apodiktisch heißt. Ja, meine Methode ist fragwürdig, extrem sogar. Aber deine Argumente sind es auch, daher passt das ziemlich gut. Sozusagen aus guter Tradition werde ich aus unserer Diskussion mal eine Frage machen. Mal sehen, was da so kommt. Ps.: Wenn du der Meinung bist, dass ich bei der Frage unsachlich war, dann bitte kommentieren oder editieren.

Answer (score 1):

Es handelt sich hier, wie bereits in einer anderen Antwort erwähnt, um ein [Präpositionalobjekt](https://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/praepositionalobjekt.php). Es nennt sich deswegen so, weil es (a) die Rolle eines Objekts einnimmt und (b) die Präposition der Kopf der Phrase ist. Daher Präpositionalobjekt.

Das Verb *gratulieren* verlangt die Präposition *zu*. Man gratuliert **zu etwas**<sup>1</sup>. Die Präposition *zu* wiederum erwartet als Kasus [den Dativ](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Dativ.html?MenuId=Word731#Anchor-zu-34807).

Es handelt sich also um ein Präpositonalobjekt, dass im Dativ steht.
"Zu wem gratuliere ich? Zu seinem Erfolg."

---

<sup>1</sup> Man kann auch *wegen etwas* oder *aufgrund von etwas* gratulieren. Wichtig ist hier aber, dass nicht beliebig ausgetauscht werden kann, sondern dass eine (oder mehrere) konkrete Präpositionen vom Verb verlangt werden.